# how to run java application with ms access database on Friends computer? it works fine on my computer

Tags: java, ms-access, jar, exe

I developed a supermarket java application (i didn't use any IDE) and converted it to jar, to exe it works fine on my computer. The problem is the program( .exe ) opens on my friends computer but doesn't really continue to log in which shows it is not linked to the ms access database.and i have no idea on how to link the application to the database. i would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: Have you set any datasource in your friend's computer?

Comment: Where is the Access database running?  On your machine?  Access was designed for desktop use.  If you want to connect to a database on a server I'd recommend getting something like SQL Server (if you want to stick with Microsoft) or MySQL - something designed to run on a server in remote fashion.   Are the two machines on a common network, or are you relying on the public internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, MS Access is intended for use on a single desktop machine, so MS Access must be installed so that an MS Access database can be used there by a java application.

This is different from some MS languages, which can use MS access databases on their machines -- create, access, change, etc. -- without the MS Access program installed.

You do not say what libraries you use -- in order to use the Access database, your Java code must be calling something that uses an MS shared library (a DLL file) that provides a way to use the database.  It is theoretically possible for the Java code to just read the database binary format, but I'm certain you did not do that.

So, if what you want is for this application to use a database that is on a different machine, you need to store the data in a system that allows network access -- SQL server, Derby, something besides Access.

If you want your application to have its own database on whatever desktop machine is running it, then you can either provide the MS Access libraries for every such machine -- bound to cost something -- or you can alter your program to use a different database.  There is actually full database functionality built into the Java runtime itself, based on a system that used to be called Derby.  It runs either as a server or as an "embedded" database used by a single program on a single machine; it is this latter use that may be the closest to what you've done already.

It is curious that you say you have "no idea how to link the application to the database"; I would have expected you to have some idea based on the code you wrote to access it in the first place.

Comment: -1 This answer contains several inaccuracies, including: (1) "MS Access must be installed..." - No, it is not necessary to install the full Access application in order to manipulate an Access database. (2) "you can ... provide the MS Access libraries for every such machine -- bound to cost something" - No, both the Access Database Engine (for Windows, from Microsoft) or UCanAccess (cross-platform) are available for free.

Comment: Fair enough - I meant the database engine, but I did name it like it was the application.  I didn't know about the cross-platform package, that's good info.  The fact remains that, to use Access, he'll need to put something on each machine; to use Derby he does not have to.

Comment: Thank you it was helpful now i understand the problems with ms access that's why i changed my database to H2 database and am hoping it will solve my problem which was linking the .exe to the database?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "linking the .exe to the database"; that phrase could several meanings.  A database is a file or a set of files that have a specific organization -- Access, Derby, and H2 each have their own organization.  Your program, which was evidently made into an EXE file by a tool that almost certainly started with a jar file, has code in it to access a particular kind of database.  In your code, you specify the location of the file(s) that contain the data, and uses libraries that understand the format of the file(s) it uses.  If that doesn't answer your question, clarify.